# UWP: read string from custom .resw file

Tags: c#, uwp

I know this question has been asked many times, but I just can't seem to find a complete answer:

I have created a .resw file called config.resw in the root of my UWP project, with the purpose of storing API keys and things like that.

Is there a way to obtain values from this file? I have tried

```
 ResourceLoader resources = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("config.resw");

 var x = resources.GetString("SomeResource");
```

but that failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the file type. This have to work:

```
ResourceLoader resources = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("config");
var x = resources.GetString("SomeResource");
```