# UWP: read all entries from custom .resw file

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to use a `.resw` file in an UWP app to store a list of information. Is it possible to get all the entries of one file? From the API it looks like the only option is to get one Value when we already know the Key.

Is the best option to use a `.csv` instead?

Comment: Hello! Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923492/uwp-read-string-from-custom-resw-file

Comment: `this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` should give you the name of all resources in the assembly of the type. Whether to use a `.csv` or `.resw` file depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From the API it looks like the only option is to get one Value when we already know the Key.

[`ResourceMap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcemap) inherit  `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, NamedResource>` interface, so you could use foreach loop to get all key then use key to get all value.

```
ResourceContext defaultContextForCurrentView = ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
ResourceMap stringResourcesResourceMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Resources"); 
foreach (var item in stringResourcesResourceMap.Keys)
{
    var res = stringResourcesResourceMap.GetValue(item, defaultContextForCurrentView).ValueAsString;
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.